# Realizar una consulta de mongoDb dentro de un for loop

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, bucle-for

Tengo un arreglo de ObjectIds. Por cada una de las ids del arreglo quiero ejecutar una consulta a MongoDb. La consulta es de tipo find().ToArray(), por lo que debería resultar en un arreglo por cada ObjectId. Probé ejecutando la consulta fuera del ciclo for y funciona perfectamente. Sin embargo, dentro del ciclo for, recibo un arreglo vacio por cada id.

Mi codigo es el siguiente :

```
getPostsFromFollowingUsers : async (req, res) => {

 

   const userId = new ObjectId(req.body.userId)

   await client.connect()
   const user = await client.db('instagram').collection('users').findOne(
       { _id : userId }
       )
      
    
    const followingUsersArray = user.following //este es arraglo de ObjectsId
    
    
    
    for(let i = 0; i < followingUsersArray.length; i++){

        const followingUser = new ObjectId(followingUsersArray[i])
        console.log(followingUser) //entrega el valor correcto. Es decir, un ObjectId
       
        
        const followingUserPostsArray = await client.db('instagram').collection('userPost').find(
            { postedByUser : followingUser}
        ).toArray() //este es el query que no funciona
       
        console.log('array of post by user', followingUserPostsArray) //imprime el mensaje y un arreglo vacio

        
        
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Literalmente no returna nada o returna ahí algún otro mensaje, como [object Object] o algo así ?

Comment: retorna un arreglo vacio []. Sin embargo, cuando realizo el query fuera del loop,, obtengo el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas usar un bucle `for`, primero porque es ineficiente (se realiza una llamada a la DB por cada elemento de tu Array) y segundo porque existe un operador de consulta especialmente diseñado para filtrar los documentos de la colección cuyo campo coincida con algún elemento de tu lista.

El operador se llama [`$in`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) y lo puedes usar de la siguiente forma:

```js
// construimos la lista de ObjectIds a partir de la lista de id de usuarios
const idList = followingUsersArray.map(id => new ObjectId(id));
const followingUserPostsArray = await client.db('instagram').collection('userPost').find(
  { postedByUser : {$in: idList }}
).toArray();
```

Con esto, en una sola llamada a la base de datos, obtienes el resultado. Puedes ver el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O8V-5QSfFXa) como ejemplo. Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.